# Github ask for Username & password after Configure ssh?

Tags: ssh, password, git, github

I have Created **SSH keygen** and Just add the Public Key to My Github Account.

When I am pushing My local Saved State to Github Repo.It ask for UserName & Password
again.

[image: 1]

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that the way you're trying to pull / push?

Comment: I mean if we are trying to push/pull changes.github will not ask for username & password

Comment: Hm, it's an old question, I don't know how I came here. Is it solved? Then you should accept your own answer.

Comment: yes.I have added the solution  in below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link Given below will solve If you'r stuck under "permission denied".I Hope it will be couple of steps, simple &  easy.

https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Above Given Information from the link are fairly self-evident

Answer (score 0):

The answer is there itself in the image.

***GITHUB does not provide shell access***

There are two options for you

1. go to the gihub website and **ask them to provide shell access.Then wait for weeks** on until they decide wether to give or not give shell access.
2. **Use your terminal** to login into github.

BTW why do you need to use shell login? It's unnecessary and incorrect.

Comment: I don't need Shell access.In terminal Git  ask for Password whenever I am going to Push

Comment: It's obvious to ask password.One can't push a repo without logging in.A point to note that `Github` asks for password even if link is incorrect.So it's good thought to recheck the link.

Comment: Github doesn't ask for password.Once If you'r added public key under ssh.

Comment: But why are you using ssh anyway?

Comment: I have Just Solved My issue `permission denied in public key`.It could be pain for frequent users commit it will ask Username & password again.So we can go around with ssh to tell github instead of password it will match ssh keys

Comment: @arunsmartarrow why don't you write an answer then? it might be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [github-keygen](https://github.com/dolmen/github-keygen) for your SSH setup. Easy and secure.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of this tool.*